# Is there a simple way to convert setup.py to pyproject.toml

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

We have multiple python projects, and are considering converting them to use `pyproject.toml` instead of `setup.py`.

Is there a simple way to automate this?

Comment: I guess something like run `python setup.py egg_info`, figure out in which file the metadata is written, parse it and write it back to a `pyproject.toml` file. Should be relatively straightforward. And should be quite reliable unless the `setup.py` files do things they should not be doing. -- I thought I had seen a tool that does this but can not find it anymore, so maybe I hallucinated.

Answer (score 22):

While dealing with some `pyproject.toml` issues, I encountered this project:

https://pypi.org/project/ini2toml/

The projects description:

> This project is experimental and under active development Issue reports and contributions are very welcome.
> The original purpose of this project is to help migrating `setup.cfg` files to PEP 621, but by extension it can also be used to convert any compatible `.ini/.cfg` file to `.toml`.

While this only helps to turn `.cfg/.ini` files to PEP 621 `.toml`, there is another project that turn setup.py files into cfg files.

https://github.com/gvalkov/setuptools-py2cfg

> This script helps convert existing setup.py files to `setup.cfg` in the format expected by setuptools.

Combining these two processes by writing a script you could potentially come up with an automated way to transform the files. I have not tried this as of yet but would be interested if you could make this idea work :)

Comment: This didn't work for me, I'm still getting build-related errors after generating the toml

Answer (score 13):

[`pdm`](https://pdm.fming.dev/latest/) supports importing metadata from various existing and older metadata files, including `setup.py`.

You can either:

1. run `pdm init` on your project root (with the old metadata files) and follow the instructions, or
2. run `pdm import setup.py` explicitly.

See [Import project metadata from existing project files](https://pdm.fming.dev/latest/usage/project/#import-the-project-from-other-package-managers) for more details.

Comment: just for records, it automatically updates the `pyproject.toml` file

Comment: but also that it didn't add even a single new line about `[build-system]`, only added the ones in the `setup()` scope from the `setup.py` file

Comment: rly helpful. It's a significant improvement to have a pyproject.toml available for pip-tools' pip-compile, juxtaposed to the setup.py  files for some older Python projects (e.g pyQode). The pdm import cmd was just so simple - will take another look at using pdm. thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the migration using [Hatch tool](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/intro/#existing-project)

Navigate to the directory where you `setup.py` is located and run

```bash
hatch new --init
```

and it will automatically migrate to the `pyproject.toml` configuration for you